# How to programmatically add widget to the centralwidget (ui generated by pyside2-uic)?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I have a generated python code from QT Designer with pyside2-uic, which is named my_ui.py looks like this:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1070, 650)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(1070, 650))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(1070, 650))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(48, 49, 46);")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        ...
```

I use another file my_logic.py to manipulate all things in my_ui.py

```
from my_ui import *

class Launcher(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(window)
        ...
```

Adding this piece of code works:

```
    self.comboBoxStatus = QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.comboBoxStatus.setObjectName(u"comboBoxStatus")
    self.comboBoxStatus.setGeometry(QRect(300, 150, 300, 100))
```

However I need to make the QComboBox be checkable, so i start by creating a new class called CheckableComboBox that inherits from QComboBox in the my_logic.py file:

```
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
```

And now when i try to add this to the centralwidget like so:

```
    self.checkableComboBoxStatus = CheckableComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.checkableComboBoxStatus.setObjectName(u"chekableComboBoxStatus")
    self.checkableComboBoxStatus.setGeometry(QRect(300, 150, 300, 100))
```

It throws an error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I tried adding QMainWindow in the **init**() like this:

```
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, QMainWindow):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(self))

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
```

The error goes away, but the dropdown doesn't appear anywhere in the GUI when i run my code.

Sorry if this is too newbish of a question, but it's above my level, i have a hard time understanding classes and sub classes in Python, especially with the use of PySide.

note: I've already looked in promoting from QtDesigner, i would like to avoid that if possible, since i am not allowed to add new libraries to the pipeline, just change the code in those 2 files.

Thank you!

Comment: change to `def __init__(self, parent=None):`
        `super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: Also provide a [mre]

Comment: my god @eyllanesc, that was supppeer fast, i was still editing my question and you provided the answer! :S

Write your comment as Answer and so i can choose it as the correct one please.
edit: it worked though!

Comment: @masky007 please consider that it's better to not try to subclass the UI class generated by pyside-uic, but instead use a subclass of the Qt widget you're using (QMainWindow in your case) and use `setupUi` of the form class instance, or, better, inherit from *both* QMainWindow and the UI class, and then call `self.setupUi(self)`. Also, widget promotion doesn't necessarily require to create new scripts for promoted classes: as long as the *main* script is properly written (most importantly, with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check), you can add the promoted classes in the same main script.

Comment: Also consider that fixed geometries are generally discouraged, as 99% of times they're chosen due to bad design or lack of knowledge/experience, and they almost always result in display issues caused by different user fonts/settings and OS styles that can even make the UI completely unusable (overlapping/hidden widgets, cut off texts, etc). Please read more about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and how to [use them in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the tips, much appreciated, ill try it out.